# Append string to jquery-ui-dialog title

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog

So basically i need to know how i can append a string to a dialog title.

for example the string is foo.

and if I run

```
$("#dialogid").dialog("option", "title", "bar")
```

in the js console, the title should be foobar.

EDIT:

basically this line of code shouldn't change. if i run specifically this line of code, the title will change to foobar

EDIT2:

So i've come up with a solution to my problem, but still i have no idea how could i make it so it would happend at once, not after 10 ms

```
$(function () {
    $("#dialogid").dialog({})
    $("#dialogid").dialog('option', 'title', 'bar');

    setInterval(function(){ 

        var title123 = $("#dialogid").dialog( "option", "title" );
        var n = title123.indexOf("foo");
        if(n < 0) {
            $("#dialogid").dialog( "option", "title", "foo" + title123);
        }

    }, 10);
});
```

Comment: my answer sort your issue ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is jsfiddle link
http://jsfiddle.net/tridip/rxV8R/18/

```
$(function () {
    $("#dialog").dialog({})
    //init title with text
    $("#dialog").dialog('option', 'title', 'Foo');

    //later change the text
    $("#dialog").dialog('option', 'title', $("#dialog").dialog('option', 'title')+' Bar');
});
```

if any area is not clear then aks me please.

Comment: your example worked, but as i edited above, the line of code i gave, shouldn't change.

Comment: when my answer worked then you should mark my answer as right or vote me up. thanks

Answer (score 1):

This should work (assuming that you want to append to the pre-existing dialog title):

```
var existingTitle = $("#dialogid").dialog("option", "title"); 
$("#dialogid").dialog( "option", existingTitle  + "bar" );
```

Comment: this works but is there any option to do it globally? i mean, that if i change the title, always the string will be added to the title, without really adding it.

Comment: you could probably add some kind of helper (or even extension) method: call it appendToDialog, and then do similar functionality to that of above.  Then, whenever you wanted to set the text (via. appending) you could just call that method.